# how to initialize common resource names in multiple junit4 test classes

Tags: java, junit4

I am creating a set of junit test classes ,all of which read from the same input data files.I created a test suite as below,but found that I would be replicating the filenames in each test class.

So, how do I do this without repeating the code..

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({SomeTests.class,someOtherTests.class})
public class AllTests{

}
-------------------
public class SomeTests{
    private String[] allfiles;

    public SomeTests() {
        allfiles = new String[] {"data1.txt","data2.txt"};
    }

    @Test
    public void testXX1(){
      //
    }

    @Test
    public void testXX2(){
      //
    }

}

public class someOtherTests{
    private String[] allfiles;

    public someOtherTests() {
        allfiles = new String[] {"data1.txt","data2.txt"};
    }

    @Test
    public void testYY(){
      //
    }

}
```

I thought I would have to make another class to provide the filenames as a String array..sothat the test classes can initialize the `allfiles` variable by calling the `getFileNames()` static method,combining this this with BeforeClass annotation

```
public class FileNames {
    public static String[] getFileNames() {
        return new String[]{"data1.txt","data2.txt"};
    }
}

public class SomeTests{
    private String[] allfiles;

    public SomeTests() {

    }

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp(){
       allfiles = FileNames.getFileNames();
    }

    @Test
    public void testXX1(){
      //
    }

    @Test
    public void testXX2(){
      //
    }

}
```

but I am not sure that is the right way. This will require setUp() to be declared as static ,and that means I will have to make the instance variable allfiles static !

I think this is a common scenario in junit testing ..so can someone please tell me how to do this properly?

Comment: No, `setUp()` will not need to be declared as static.  There is nothing wrong with having a member method call a static method.  What you've done is fine. But I wouldn't even bother having an `allFiles` var unless you are going to change its contents during your tests (unlikely).  Instead just call the static `getFileNames()` whenever you need it.

Comment: I got this error running the test suite `java.lang.Exception: Method setUp() should be static
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoid(FrameworkMethod.java:84)
 ...`

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Before` instead of `@BeforeClass`, then your `setUp()` method need not be static.

However, unless you are going to modify your filename array in your tests, you could also create a base class for your tests and declare a protected constant with those names:

```
public class FileBasedTests {
  protected static final String[] FILENAMES = {"data1.txt","data2.txt"}
}

public class SomeTests extends FileBasedTests {
  ...
}
```

If you really are concerned about each test having its own copy of those file names, you can write `allFiles = FILENAMES.clone()`.